# OpenGL stencil test does not work as expected

Tags: c++, opengl

OpenGL stencil testing does not work as expected in old OpenGL versions. So I use the following test rendering code to find out what is wrong:

```
int imgWidth = 256;
int imgHeight = 256;
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearStencil(0);
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

// Render invisible triangle.
glColorMask(false, false,false,false);
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0, 0x1);
glStencilMask(1);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_INVERT);
glColor4ub(0,0,0,0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
 glVertex2d(0,0);
 glVertex2d(128,128);
 glVertex2d(128,0);
glEnd();

// Enable color rendering
glColorMask(true,true,true,true);

// Render renctangle with a triangle hole in it.
glStencilMask(0xff);
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0x0, 0xff);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP,GL_KEEP,GL_KEEP);
glColor4ub(255,0,0,0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
 glVertex2d(0,0);
 glVertex2d(imgWidth,0);
 glVertex2d(imgWidth,imgHeight);
 glVertex2d(0,imgHeight);
glEnd();
```

The code above works as expected in my OpenGL 3.3 machine. But failed at OpenGL 1.4 machine , there is no hole in the renctangle. I tried to modify the stencil related parameters only to find that OpenGL seems to ignore the stencil test compeletely. Cannot figure out why.

Comment: Did you verify (via `glGet()` with `GL_STENCIL_BITS`) that the GL context you got from the OS actually has some stencil bits?

Comment: @genpfault that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @genpfault said **glGetIntergerv(GL_STENCIL_BITS, bits)** get 0 stencil bits. That explains what happened.

Ways to solve the problem: Under Windows change the *cStencilBits* of **PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR** to the desired number of bits (e.g. 8) when creating the rendering context.

However, that doesn't explain why stencil works fine under OpenGL verion 3.3. Higher version of OpenGL may force the stencil bits non-zero I guess. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Not sure why the behavior would change between versions on the same machine. But generally, what you specify in the PFD is only a *minimum* of bits you want for the buffer. So it's possible that you get a stencil buffer even if you keep the value at 0. That's more likely if you ask for a depth buffer, since depth and stencil are often stored in the same buffer internally.

Comment: It's not on the same machine. Forgot to mention that.